# how to setup a mysql table for use with UPDATE WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, create-table, sql-update

I have a table that i store userinfo. Each user has a unique userid, but the rest of their information varies.

When i try to run a statement to UPDATE that table, where userid = $userid, i get a `Duplicate entry 'XXX' for key 'userid'` where XXX is their userid.

I have the userid field set as unique, but obviously ive done something wrong somewhere.

Here is my statement

```
UPDATE `users` SET `screenname` =  '$screenname' ,`real_name` =  '$real_name' ,`profimg` =  '$profimg'  WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `screenname` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `real_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `profimg` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: are you using PHP to do the query ?

Comment: thta's quite strange, Mysql basically says you are trying to do INSERT, not UPDATE. check your code.

Comment: <? echo "yes i am  "; ?>

Comment: <?php die('show me the code then'); ?>

Comment: @dusoft gets the win on this one, chalk it up to a learning experience

Comment: @Patrick: it was a auto incrment problem really ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should use a primary key index instead of a unique index. A primarey key index disables null entries, and although you set the collumn to NOT NULL it's better to use a PK index, since the collumn is in fact the primary key for the table.

try redefining your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `screenname` text NOT NULL,
  `real_name` text NOT NULL,
  `profimg` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `useridKey` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

You could also have a look at the [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) collumn attribute.
Also be sure to escape your variables before putting them into your query to negate sql injections...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using PHP. did you put query in double quotes like

```
$sql = "UPDATE foobar SET bar = '$foo' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

if you used single quote PHP **won't replace** your variables